# How to filter out headers during HTTP redirect in Camel?

Tags: http, apache-camel

In my Camel SpringBoot app I send a request (which includes a number of specific HTTP headers) and receive the 302 from the remote service. Camel automatically follows the redirect but includes all headers previously set, which causes some problems on the other side. Is there any way to control this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious is to remove specific headers in the Camel route with

```
.removeHeaders("Camel*")
```

This of course must be **done for every header pattern** and also **multiple times** if you have multiple outbound connections.

But Camel also has the **[concept of a `HeaderFilterStrategy`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html#Howtoavoidsendingsomeorallmessageheaders-UseHeaderFilterStrategy)**. Most components have a default implementation that is used by default.

In the case of HTTP this is `HttpHeaderFilterStrategy`. It is applied for all HTTP connections and filters the following headers:

- content-length
- content-type
- host
- cache-control
- connection
- date
- pragma
- trailer
- transfer-encoding
- upgrade
- via
- warning
- Camel*
- org.apache.camel*

You are free to **implement your own custom `HeaderFilterStrategy`** or extend one of Camel. You can then register it as a Spring bean and configure your endpoints to use it where needed.

```
.to("http:myEndpoint?&headerFilterStrategy=#myHeaderFilter") // myHeaderFilter = name of the Spring bean
```

Comment: Well, the problem is, `removeHeaders` doesn't help. Here's what happens. I call the service A and need to pass the Authorization header. Service A returns 302 and redirects to the service B which complains about the Authorization header as it does not expect it. I'm trying to find a way to control the headers during the redirect.

Comment: I just tried to implement a simple filter strategy, but it is only invoked before the first HTTP request, but not before the redirect.

Comment: Sounds like the redirect is done "internally" in the HTTP library used and not by Camel. Do you use Camel HTTP for the request?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by creating a custom HTTP configurer which adds an interceptor to the request, e.g.

```
public class RedirectHttpClientConfigurer implements HttpClientConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder) {
        clientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst(new RedirectInterceptor());
    }

    public class RedirectInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {

        @Override
        public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            Object httpResponseContextAttr = context.getAttribute("http.response");
            if (httpResponseContextAttr != null) {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) httpResponseContextAttr;
                int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode > 299 && statusCode < 399) {
                    request.removeHeaders("Authorization");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I configured it as a bean:

```
<spring:bean id="redirectConfigurer" class="com.foo.bar.RedirectHttpClientConfigurer"/>
```

and referenced it in the endpoint:

```
<to uri="http://com.foo.bar?httpClientConfigurer=#redirectConfigurer"/>
```